# Evaluate two lossy compression algorithms

Tags: model-evaluation, metric, compression

I am trying to evaluate several methods to compress some 2D data points.
The algorithm itself is not relevant, but from the output, I can compute the MSE and the number of points (which can be used to calculate the compression ratio).
Is there any metric that combines compression quality (MSE) with the resulting number of points (compression ratio)?

Comment: +1 but you might have better luck on the [signal processing Stack](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ideally, of course, you don't really want MSE for e.g. image compression, but rather how much loss of information humans perceive.

Comment: @Björn Agreed. For instance, loss at the edge probably isn’t as important as loss in the middle where attention will be focused.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the question on Signal Processing. The data is not one image, is a sequence of x,y points.